# Conditonal Rendering of components

Tags: reactjs, coding-style

I find myself writing code like this quite frequently, to avoid deeply nested statements to determine return values e.g.:

```
function Warning(props){
   return <h1> Warning! </h1>
}
 
function SomeComponent(props){
   const [showAtTop, setShowAtTop] = useState(false); 
    
   //...

   const ShowWarningAtTop = showAtTop
      ? <Warning></Warning>
      : null
   const ShowAtBottom = showAtTop
      ? null
      : <Warning></Warning>


   return <div>
      {showWarningAtTop}
      <div> Main Content</div>
      {showWarningAtBottom}
   </div>
}
```

I'm not 100% satisfied with that solution, (repetetive code, return statement gets somewhat bloated and it's quite hard to look at the return statement to see whats happening)  and i'm anxious that it's considered bad style. Is there a more readable / cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorter/simpler conditional rendering using logical AND (`&&`).

[Inline If with Logical && Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

React ignores booleans in output. Only react components *need* to return `null` to indicate they are rendering nothing, anything *within* a component can return true/false and react will ignore and not render the literal value.

You can also self-close empty tags in JSX.

```
function SomeComponent(props){
   const [showAtTop, setShowAtTop] = useState(false); 
    
   //...

   return (
     <div>
       {showAtTop && <Warning />}
       <div> Main Content</div>
       {showAtTop && <Warning />}
     </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: Yep, `<Warning></Warning>` can also be `<Warning />`

Comment: I feel really stupid now i've been using that syntax for strings and such never occured to me that I could do it with entire Components / Objects.

Comment: @xtr No worries, brain farts can happen to any of us at any time. If this was what you were looking for then please accept answer so others know it is resolved. Cheers.